# Are (STFT + LTFT) values less than +/- 38% really normal for 2002 Toyota RAV4?

Tags: toyota, rav4, fuel-trims

According to a 2002 Toyota RAV4 Repair Manual, "If total of short-term fuel trim value and long-term fuel trim value is within plus or minus 38 percent, the system is functioning normally."

Based on fuel trim posts that I've read or watched, this range seems a bit excessive.

Can anyone "validate" these ranges as being "normal" for assuming no known mechanical issues and codes in the vehicle?

Comment: generally +/- 10% ltft is acceptable anything more would probably set a code. +/- 38% total fuel trim still seems excessive and would likely cause a code as well.On Toyota's when AFR sensor goes bad or a vacuum leak occurs you'd see ~ +25 ltft.

Comment: @Ben - Yes, +/- 10% seems to be the "normal" good range. However, I can confirm that codes are NOT being set for total FT > 10% or even up to +28%.  This assumes scanner, PCM, and AFS (up-stream sensors) are operating normally.

Comment: I don't have a capture from a 2.0 Rav4 but I do have a capture from a 02 1.8 Corolla with a p0171 code and total fuel trim of + 21% at idle ltft +23% STFT -2% FWIW. If you see low LTFT at idle and cruise you can assume the system is working normally for the most part.

Comment: @Ben - copy/paste from 2002 Engine Performance, Self Diagnostics, Test With Codes section; "When DTC P0171 exists, the actual air/fuel ratio is to lean. When DTC P0172 exists, the actual air/fuel ratio is to rich. If total of short-term fuel trim value and long-term fuel trim value is within plus or minus 38 percent, the system is functioning normally."